# when using moq, I have to know all methods that will be used?

Tags: moq

when I use moq for my database factory, do I need to moq ALL the methods or just the ones that will be called?

or is that the beauty of using moq, where I just have to add moq methods for the ones I will use?

Answer (score 1):

Just the ones you use.

This applies to most, if not all mocking/faking frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to mock *all* of the methods that will be called, only the ones that have to return something or that you want confirmation that it was called.

Comment: Though be careful that in general, the "confirmation that it was called" bit should be done as the last part of your AAA triumvirate - the Assert section (in some cases if you both need it to be called and need to set up a return value, you might need to 'mentiohn' it twice. (@Randolpho: Feel free to edit this in if you consider it relevant)